# How to remove a UIButton once it is clicked in swift xcode 13.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift and Xcode.  I am creating a button in my UIViewController like this:

```
    func addNewPlayerButton(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, view: UIView, color: UIColor) {
        let startButton = UIButton()
        startButton.frame.size.width = width
        startButton.frame.size.height = height
        startButton.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        
        startButton.backgroundColor = color
        startButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "can_add"), for: .normal)
        
        startButton.addTarget(self,
                         action: #selector(removeButton),
                         for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(startButton)
    }

    @objc
    func removeButton() {
        ???
    }
```

I want to remove the button after it is clicked and add a new button in its place.  However, I cannot figure out how to remove a button using the #selector.  I first considered putting the view as a parameter to the selector, but I was unsure how to add it.

Comment: "but I found this impossible" Well, you found wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
func removeButton() {
```

to

```
func removeButton(_ theButton: UIButton) {
```

Now you have a reference to the button and can do what you like with it.